# Quicksight control to include nulls

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a quicksight dataset where one of the data fields is routingtype which can be filled with "Agent_direct", "agent_select" and "null" as the values. I have created a parameter and filter linked to the parameter but when I create the control and link it back to the dataset and routingtype field I am unable to filter by null values in the control. Is there a way to include those in the control?[routing type control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5srp.png)

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution. Do you find something?